# PostgreSQL - SELECT duplicate data depending on 3 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE cameras
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sq_streams'::regclass),
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  exid text NOT NULL,
  owner_id integer NOT NULL,
  is_public boolean NOT NULL,
  config json NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  last_polled_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  is_online boolean,
  timezone text,
  last_online_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  location geography(Point,4326),
  mac_address macaddr,
  model_id integer,
  discoverable boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  preview bytea,
  thumbnail_url text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_streams PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have 5000 records in this. What i am trying to get is the result below : 
There are 57 Cameras and they have everything different but 3 things are the same, which are

```
'external_http_port', config->> 'external_host', config-> 'snapshots'->> 'jpg'
```

I want to create a query which will show me results as

```
external_http_port | external_host | config-> 'snapshots'->> 'jpg' | Count
"93.87.73.118"     | "1024"        |      "/oneshotimage.jpg"      | 57
"180.180.180.48"   |  "81"         |"/onvif/media_service/snapshot"|20
```

Comment: edited! Do you have an answer?

Comment: You didn't show input data, you didn't show what output you're getting.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq it is very unclear what you want. Please rephrase like we are a no-brain golden retriever

Comment: @JunaidFarooq, please explain it well. I still don't have a good understanding of your issue and I spent some precious time on it... :)

Comment: @JunaidFarooq Much clearer. If I get you well, You want every `external_http_port` , `external_host` and `config` , the 3 columns will act like an index and you will see how many identical records for the 3 columns you have. Is my understanding good enough?

Comment: Sorry. But you are not getting, all 3 external_http_port, external_host and snapshots->jpg are in CONFIG object which is of type json. thats why i was using config->'external_host'. to get this value

Comment: @JunaidFarooq It is still unclear then ...

Comment: You are not getting me. its normal thing, table having an object of json type , you may leave json, just consider three columns and then all the things i have defined you @AndyK

Comment: @JunaidFarooq First thing: If I'm not getting you, then probably the issue is not with me. You want people to understand you, you get clearer in your explanation first.

Comment: Actually i have stuck on this issue and have done so many R&D about it, now please help me if you can\

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I cannot help you if I cannot understand what you want to achieve. Ask one of your colleague if he can understand you first. http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this?

```
SELECT config ->>'external_http_port' AS external_http_port, 
       config->> 'external_host' AS external_host, 
       config-> 'snapshots'->> 'jpg' AS snapshots,
       count(*) 
FROM cameras  
GROUP BY config->>'external_http_port', config->> 'external_host', config-> 'snapshots'->> 'jpg' 
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hi @tommaso-di-bucchianico `OP` doesn't want that. I gave a similar answer to yours and he said my answer is not correct

Comment: This is exactly what I understand from the question, so my upvote. OP is saying "you don't get met" Andy, Don't worry I don't get something else than this either :)

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz #lmao pal. I feel `OP` wanted something spot on instead of having the reasonning. But well, I've done that before ... Who am I to judge? All the best dear `OP`

Answer (score 0):

Would it do the trick? (Think as an analogy, instead of litterally)

```
CREATE TABLE stacktest
(col1 VARCHAR(8),
col2 VARCHAR(8),
col3 VARCHAR(8))


INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('A','B','C')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('A','B','C')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('A','B','C')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('A','B','C')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('A','B','C')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('A','B','C')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('C','A','B')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('C','A','B')
INSERT INTO stacktest VALUES ('C','A','B')


SELECT col1,col2,col3 
FROM stacktest
GROUP BY  col1,col2,col3
HAVING (COUNT(col1)>3 AND COUNT(col2) >3 AND COUNT(col3) > 3)
```

Comment: No its not. Sorry for not explaining it well. 
i want to count such rows in which those 3 columns have same value which i have mentioned above